# VBA - getting 'mysql server is --read-only' error but only when using RecordSet

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have the following sub:

```
Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
    "SERVER=server;" & _
    "DATABASE=db;" & _
    "USER=user;" & _
    "PASSWORD=pass;" & _
    "Option=3"


Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = oConn

table_name = Sheets("Master").Range("S2").Value

SQLstr = "Select * From " & table_name
rst.Open SQLstr, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For rowindx = 2 To lRow
    rst.AddNew
        For fieldIndx = 1 To lCol
            rst.Fields(Cells(1, fieldIndx).Value) = Cells(rowindx, fieldIndx).Value
        Next fieldIndx
Next rowindx
rst.UpdateBatch

rst.Close
oConn.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set oConn = Nothing

MsgBox ("Query Successful")
```

This gives me the "The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute the statement" at the rst.AddNew step.

However, when I run  a separate function attached to a different macro (same database, same server), everything gets executed as expected. **The database is not read-only.**

```
Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
    "SERVER=server;" & _
    "DATABASE=database;" & _
    "USER=user;" & _
    "PASSWORD=password;" & _
    "Option=3"


Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = oConn

cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.Execute

oConn.Close
MsgBox ("Query Successful")
```

What's wrong with the first block? Does recordset default to read-only?

Comment: Late where I am and I can't find any helpful pages for you, will look in the morning. Recordsets do indeed open read only but there is an argument in the constructor and a separate method also to make them read write. In RW state you need to call the update function every line you update e.g. recSet.fields(3) = "SomeValue": recDet.Update: recSet.MoveNext. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ah ok. I can try to find something too but that's good to know. Tricky to find VBA documentation...

Comment: Here's the manual for Access VBA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/access/object-model and for Excel VBA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model

Answer (score 0):

Just had to change 'adLockOptimistic' to 'adLockBatchOptimistic'